# How can I sove future warning in jupiternote book which later create NameError?

Tags: nameerror

C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py:432: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)

Answer (score 0):

Just type when you call LogisticRegression:

```
LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
```